# How can I extract just the first record in a "one to many" relationship via LINQ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using MVC3, C#, .NET4, EF5.
I am using the ASP.NET Membership provider.
I am using one role per user, although the model supports 1 user many roles.

I need to extract this one role in LINQ queries when extracting user information. In essence I just need the "First()" Role record for a given user.

I have an Application User table which maps 1 to 1 with the AspNet.Membership table.

So something like:

```
List<StdOrgUser> myUsers = Model.Select(i => new StdOrgUser(){
    Id=i.Id,
    Rolename = i.Aspnet_Membership.Aspnet_Users.Aspnet_Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleName
}).ToList();
```

Also Intellisense allowed me to write the above code, it does not run in practice.
How should I get this one rolename value alongside my user details for this record?
This model will go into a WebGrid for display.

EDIT:

My amended code, pre null testing advice!

```
var myUsers = Model.Select(i => new{ 
    Id = i.Id, 
    Firstname = i.Firstname, 
    initials = i.Initials, 
    Lastname = i.Lastname, 
    Username = i.Aspnet_Membership.Aspnet_Users.UserName, 
    RoleName = i.Aspnet_Membership.Aspnet_Users.Aspnet_Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleName, 
        Organisation = i.StdOrg.Name 
}).ToList();
```

EDIT2: Post null testing:

```
var myUsers = Model.Select(i => new { 
    Id = i.Id, 
    Firstname = i.Firstname, 
    initials = i.Initials, 
    Lastname = i.Lastname, 
    Username = i.Aspnet_Membership.Aspnet_Users.UserName, 
    RoleName = i.Aspnet_Membership.Aspnet_Users.Aspnet_Roles.Any() ? i.Aspnet_Membership.Aspnet_Users.Aspnet_Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleName : "No Roles",
        Organisation = i.StdOrg.Name 
    }).ToList();
```

I then feed this second model into my webgrid.

Comment: looks fine to me, whats the error?

Comment: You should really check to see if the user has at least one role first. This will throw a `NullReferenceException` if the user has no roles: `Rolename=i.Aspnet_Membership.Aspnet_Users.Aspnet_Roles.Any() ? i.Aspnet_Membership.Aspnet_Users.Aspnet_Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleName : "No Roles";`

Comment: Initial error was that the specified domain object had no explicit property called "Rolename", so now just using "New{}" which works.  Good point about null testing @RGraham. Thanks.

Comment: Also, as a comment, I have decided for better or worse, to create a second model with the above shaping. My Webgrid then addresses the properties of this second model. Whether this is the right approach I am unsure, but it certainly works and allows me total flexibility to extract what I need from the incoming domain model. Arguably if I was using a ViewModel then I would not need to do this. I may be able to do this "shaping" directly from the webgrid, but I have not discovered an approach that works as yet.

Comment: Why allow multiple roles if you only want one? Null possible is easily removed by assigning user to default rule when created. If you use firstordefault() how can you be sure which role you are getting off there are multiple roles you should be using a simple 1to1 relation

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your access of the RoleName property up the query pipeline a little bit. Currently you're doing this:

```
i.Aspnet_Membership.Aspnet_Users.Aspnet_Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleName
```

So if `Aspnet_Roles.FirstOrDefault()` returns the default (`null`) you get a null ref exception. Instead, you should project `Aspnet_Roles` to `RoleName` *first*, then use `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
 i.Aspnet_Membership.Aspnet_Users.Aspnet_Roles.Select(ar => ar.RoleName).FirstOrDefault()
```

If you need to substitute in a default role, you can just coalesce:

```
 i.Aspnet_Membership.Aspnet_Users.Aspnet_Roles.Select(ar => ar.RoleName).FirstOrDefault() ?? "No Role"
```

This makes your query less verbose when compared to using `Any` to check for nulls (and it'll be more efficient on the SQL side, too).

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

```
var query =
    from i in Model
    from r in i
        .Aspnet_Membership
        .Aspnet_Users
        .Aspnet_Roles
        .Take(1)
    select new StdOrgUser()
    {
        Id = i.Id,
        Rolename = r.RoleName
    };

List<StdOrgUser> myUsers = query.ToList();
```